# Reroll dices in yahtzee game

Tags: java, arrays

I´m trying to create a simple yahtzee game where an array is filled with 5 random numbers and where the player can choose to roll specific dices again. However I cant figure out how to write the method that is supposed to replace specific numbers in the array with new random numbers and return it. Any suggestions how to approach this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YatzyGame {

    private final Integer NBROFDICE = 5;
    private final Integer DICEMAXVALUE = 6;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void startGame() {
        int[] dice = new int[NBROFDICE];
        rollDice(dice);
        printDice(dice);

        System.out.println("Do you want to reroll any dices? " + "Y/N");
        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            rerollDice(dice);

        } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            calculateSum(dice);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong command!");
        }

    }

    public int[] rollDice(int[] dice) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            dice[i] = rnd.nextInt(DICEMAXVALUE) + 1;
        }
        return dice;
    }

    public int[] rerollDice(int[] dice) {
        System.out.println("What dices do you want to reroll? Dices index are 0-4");
        int diceToReroll = keyboard.nextInt();

        // Replace the numbers at the index the user specifies with new random numbers and return the array.

    }

    public void printDice(int[] dices) {

        System.out.println("Your dices show: " + Arrays.toString(dices));
    }

    public void calculateSum(int[] dices) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : dices) {
            sum += i;
        }
        if (sum == 30) {
            System.out.println("YAHTZEE! Your total score is 50! Congratulations!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Your total score is: " + sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new YatzyGame().startGame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Loop through the characters in the string. For each character that is a digit, find its integer value (0-4), and reroll that die.

Comment: You could make your `rollDice` method a bit more flexible and only let it roll one dice. Then you can call it from `rollAllDices(int[] dices)` to make a whole roll and from `rerollDice(int index, int[] dices)` to only roll one dice.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] rollDice(int[] dice) {

             System.out.println("What dice do you want to reroll? Dices index are 0-4");
             int diceToRoll = keyboard.nextInt();
             dice[diceToRoll] = rnd.nextInt(DICEMAXVALUE) + 1;
    }
```

Like this you can make a function:

```
public int[] reroll(int amountOfRerolls, int[] dices){

    for(int i =0;i<dicesToReroll;i++){
       this.rollDice(dices);
    }


return dices; 
}
```

This makes the programm a bit more modal since you can reuse your `rollDice()` method wherever you need it. Also you could expand it a bit by handing in the indexes that are allowed to be rerolled in case needed.

edit: style

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Question, would it help me to create a separate Die class for this project?

Comment: You can do that of course! And it might be good to learn the concepts of OOP. I would not say it's necessary here since a die is just a `int ` value at the moment. One reason to do so might be for example if you want to store more information in a dice than it's rolled value (e.g. `boolean alreadyRolled; ` etc. )
edit: spelling